# Does anyone have an example of merging-concatenating chunks of files stored in an AWS S3 Bucket?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, multipart-upload

Currently, we are merging some output files through C# because we used to have these chunks in a drive on a server but now we are going to move these files directly from Snowflake to the S3 Bucket so it should be better to merge these files on the S3 bucket, we know that AWS has some function call **Multipart Upload** but we don't know if we could upload these files from Snowflake to S3 using that functionality.

At this moment we are exploring options, most of what we found is that we could create a lambda function for merging the files that are already in the S3 Bucket but the examples that we found are made mostly in python and our app is on .NET we also found about AWS Glue Crawler but we are not very sure about going with this option, Multipart Upload could be a good option but we lack experience with this type of implementations, so any help or example is welcome.

Comment: Just out of interest, if the data is in Snowflake why can’t you write it out as a single file rather than multiple files that you subsequently merge?

Comment: The app processes the data and takes this temp data in chunks files, then chunk by chunk is moved to the S3 from Snowflake, but I will ask about this, they just gave me the task and I only know the C# code, but the Snowflake process is a complete mystery for me.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Glue Crawler would be perfect in this situation.

1. Use a crawler to get the schema
2. Use a Glue ETL job to merge the files and write them back to S3
3. Make sure to turn on job bookmark(I will skip the previously merged files)

Example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-samples-legislators.html

Comment: Will the file size affect the performance while using the AWS Glue Crawler? Because the average size of the chunks files is 1gb and at the end, the final size of the file could be up to 250gb

Comment: Glue is a Big data ETL tool. 1 GB files are absolutely okay.